# Looping through the factors and compare two different rows and columns

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame similar to this. The code is shown below

```r
data <- data.frame( 
    Details = c("PNR1", "PNR1", "PNR11", "PNR2", "PNR2"), 
    FromCity = c("MAA", "BLR", "DEL", "TRV", "HYD"), 
    ToCity = c("BLR", "MAA", "MAA", "HYD", "TRV")
)
```

The output should be similar to this below

```
     Details FromCity ToCity
1    PNR1      MAA    BLR
2    PNR1      BLR    MAA
3    PNR11     DEL    MAA
4    PNR2      TRV    HYD
5    PNR2      HYD    TRV
```

What I want to do is to create another column based on the condition that if the `FromCity` of one row is equal to the `ToCity` of the next row, then it shoud return `"R"` otherwise it will return `"O"` in the new column.

My final output should look like this.

[image]

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Details = c("PNR1", "PNR1", "PNR1", "PNR2", "PNR2"
), FromCity = c("MAA", "BLR", "DEL", "TRV", "HYD"), ToCity = c("BLR", 
"MAA", "MAA", "HYD", "TRV")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Please help in coding this. You can consider each PNR as a different categorical variable and that's what I thought of doing to run the loop over each factor.

Comment: Would your last row of the expected output technically be equal to NA, as we don't have the next row to ascertain the status of the Type column?

Comment: Also your example data you provided does not much your expected outcome. The ToCity should equal this: ToCity = c("BLR", "MAA", "MAA", "HYD", "TRV") to match your expected output

Comment: Basically the PNR2 is for a single ID and he has the to and fro journey. So, I want to find out if the ID is a return type or oneway type.

Comment: Oh so it needs to be a by group, and the group is the details. Ok. well my answer I provided is wrong lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
require(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(Details) %>% 
  mutate(ToCityLag = lead(ToCity))
```

The lead function returns the next value of a selected column. With this information you can create your column with an if_else.

Comment: Gives me some column values as NA

Comment: In that case, you want to populate your new column with "O"